# Bootstrap 5.2 carousel error - control buttons move up and transition not working

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-carousel

I'm trying to implement the bootstrap carousel on multiple cards, and it's not working - the previous/next buttons move up and the transition is not smooth

Any ideas on how I can fix this would be appreciated.

See gif of screen and how it looks: http://www.giphy.com/gifs/tXQwy9oISoYHIHWr7A

[Nav buttons error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTJIZ.jpg)

[Transition error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf0s1.jpg)

```css
.card {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 6px 8px 0 rgba(22, 22, 26, 0.18);
}

.carousel-inner {
  padding: 1em;
}

.carousel-item {
  transition: transform 2s ease, opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}

.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  background: #2e8c9d;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 6vh;
  height: 6vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.carousel-control-prev span,
.carousel-control-next span {
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

@media (min-width: 577px) {
  .cards-wrapper {
    display: flex;
  }

  .card {
    margin: 0 0.5em;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
  }

  .image-wrapper {
    height: 22vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .card:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
}

.image-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="TBC" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Auto huren bij Pickup huren Bonaire- Pickup huren Bonaire</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@700&family=Poppins:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5bc39eabb2.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div
        id="carouselExampleControls"
        class="carousel slide d-none d-sm-block"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
      >
        <div class="carousel-inner full_display">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="cards-wrapper">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="image-wrapper">
                  <img
                    src="https://pickuphurenbonaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/IMG_3732-scaled.jpeg"
                    class="img-fluid"
                    alt="..."
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make
                    up the bulk of the card's content.
                  </p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <div class="image-wrapper">
                  <img
                    src="https://pickuphurenbonaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/IMG_5215-scaled.jpeg"
                    class="img-fluid"
                    alt="..."
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make
                    up the bulk of the card's content.
                  </p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                <div class="image-wrapper">
                  <img
                    src="https://pickuphurenbonaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/IMG_5204-scaled.jpeg"
                    class="img-fluid High-deck"
                    alt="..."
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make
                    up the bulk of the card's content.
                  </p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="cards-wrapper">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img
                  src="https://pickuphurenbonaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/IMG_5204-scaled.jpeg"
                  class="img-fluid High-deck"
                  alt="..."
                />
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img
                  src="https://pickuphurenbonaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/IMG_1600-scaled.jpeg"
                  class="img-fluid"
                  alt="..."
                />
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img
                  src="https://pickuphurenbonaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/IMG_0725-scaled.jpeg"
                  class="img-fluid"
                  alt="..."
                />
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-prev"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
          data-bs-slide="prev"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-next"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
          data-bs-slide="next"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div
        id="carouselExampleControlsSmallScreen"
        class="carousel slide d-sm-none"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
      >
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img
                  src="https://pickuphurenbonaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/IMG_3732-scaled.jpeg"
                  class="img-fluid"
                  alt="..."
                />
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img
                  src="https://pickuphurenbonaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/IMG_5215-scaled.jpeg"
                  class="img-fluid"
                  alt="..."
                />
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img
                  src="https://pickuphurenbonaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/IMG_5204-scaled.jpeg"
                  class="img-fluid High-deck"
                  alt="..."
                />
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img
                  src="https://pickuphurenbonaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/IMG_5204-scaled.jpeg"
                  class="img-fluid High-deck"
                  alt="..."
                />
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img
                  src="https://pickuphurenbonaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/IMG_1600-scaled.jpeg"
                  class="img-fluid"
                  alt="..."
                />
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="image-wrapper">
                <img
                  src="https://pickuphurenbonaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/IMG_0725-scaled.jpeg"
                  class="img-fluid"
                  alt="..."
                />
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-prev"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControlsSmallScreen"
          data-bs-slide="prev"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-next"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControlsSmallScreen"
          data-bs-slide="next"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are including `bootstrap.min.css` twice

Comment: Good catch! But it's still not working unfortunately :'(